# How to count different elements in Vector using java?

Tags: java, collections

I have a lot of words at hand. What I need to do is to save them and count every different word. The original data may contain some duplicate words.Firstly, I want to use Set, then I can guarantee that I only get the different wrods. But how can I count their times? Is there someone having any "clever" idea?

Comment: You could start by reading the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for your suggestion. I have tried to find a clever way in the Java API, but I don't get it. What I want to is an easy way to implement the goal, not a complicated or stupid one.

Comment: Well, you know you want a [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), why not start there and see where it takes you.  Try something and if you get stuck, ask ;)

Comment: Ok, I know what you mean. Perhaps what I need mostly is to become familiar enough with the API. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `MultiSet` from the Guava library.

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html

Comment: That's just what I need. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Map to solve this problem.

```
String sample = " I have a problem here. I have a lot of words at hand. What I need to do is to save them and count every different word. The original data may contains duplicate words.Firstly, I want to use Set, then I can guarantee that I only get the different wrods. But how can I count their times? Is there someone having any clever idea?";
    String[] array = sample.split("[\\s\\.,\\?]");
    Map<String,Integer> statistic = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
    for (String elem:array){
        String trimElem = elem.trim();
        Integer count = 0;
        if(!"".equals(trimElem)){
            if(statistic.containsKey(trimElem)){
                count = statistic.get(trimElem);
            }
            count++;
            statistic.put(trimElem,count);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, that's really a much clever way to achieve the goal. But it may be more convenient way to use a `MultiSet` suggested by `sgp15`. Do you think so? By the way, your code is useful enough to me. Thank you!

Comment: The trade-off is code simplicity vs. introducing an extra library. I would use Guava for this if I needed it anyway, but would use this answer if not.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use hash, in java, it's HashMap(or HashSet?)
you can hash every word, and if that word has been hashed, increment some value associated with it by one, that is the idea.